# How to change the compiler on Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

How to change the compiler of Qt Creator? I installed **MinGW** (for 32 bits and 64 bits) and I configured it in the Qt Creator options (for C, C++, and gdb).

[image: Qt Creator]

But when I compile, the compiler doesn't use "My MinGW".

It uses its own compiler, which produces these errors:

```
In file included from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/filesystem:37,
                 from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32/bits/stdc++.h:127,
                 from ..\PCPhone4C++\website.hpp:10,
                 from ..\PCPhone4C++\website.cpp:1:
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h: In member function 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path& std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::operator/=(const std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&)':
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw810_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h:237:47: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' and 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path')
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
```

I don't install MinGW in `C:/QT/Tools/` but on my D disk `D:/MinGW/`.

So how can I change the default compiler of my project ?

Comment: It is necessary also to choose the kit that includes the compiler you want from Projects -> Build & Run (from the left of Qt Creator). Have you chosen it?

Comment: You probably need to set an appropriate mkspec for it. The C and C++ options on that page are kind of misleading if you aren't using cmake, because all of the important configuration options actually come from your mkspec, which is autodetected. So even if you set those options to 'clang++' on linux, it'll still use the default 'g++' compiler unless you set your mkspec to `linux-clang`. I think you probably want the `win32-g++` mkspect (or `win32-clang`). Take a look in your Qt install's mkspecs folder to see all the options.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  atakli and Ipiano, I find the solution.

I just had to go to my project, in "Build & Run" (from the left of Qt Creator) and set my own compiler for my project.